# Is it possible to call this event handler in this case?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling

I am using C# in WinForms to use a trackbar as follows. At the beginning of the code I define the event handler:

```
this.trackBar1.Scroll += new System.EventHandler(this.trackBar1_Scroll);
```

And here is the implementation when one scrolls the trackbar:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something...
}
```

So this works, but I need to call the above function from inside another event handler such as:

```
public void numericUpDown1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //what to do here to call trackBar1_Scroll ?
}
```

What could be done to call trackBar1_Scroll from inside numericUpDown1_TextChanged?

Comment: Do you want something like: `trackBar1_Scroll(trackBar1, EventArgs.Empty)` or `trackBar1_Scroll(numericUpDown1, EventArgs.Empty)` or `trackBar1_Scroll(null, null)` ?

Comment: trackBar1_Scroll(null, null) would be adequate

Comment: @Steve That didn't not work. I already tried. It moves the trackbar but it does not call  trackBar1_Scroll.

Comment: Yes checked. But what about writing a common method callable both from the Scroll event and from the TextChanged event?

Comment: @Steve You mean adding to this.trackBar1.Scroll += new System.EventHandler(this.trackBar1_Scroll); ?  I actually dont know how to implement it to call from both.

Comment: No, I mean, inside the Scroll event call a method (something like CommonHandler) and pass whatever parameter you need. The same method will be called from the TextChanged event with the same parameters.

Comment: Why don't you simply set the `TrackBar.Value`? Using the`NumericUpDown.ValueChanged` event, not the `TextChanged` event. You need values, not Text.

Comment: @Jimi it seems that inside the Scroll event there is some code that needs to be run also if the NumericUpdown/TextBox changes. So to avoid duplicating code or calling an event handler directly from another eventhandler you could use a common method

Comment: I just wonder if the duplicate post answers your question or you used the approach that I suggested (handling ValueChanged), as I believe the linked post may be a duplicate based on the title, ignoring the real requirement. I assume you have a TrackBar and a NumericUpDown which you want to keep their values sync, on the other hand you want to do something based on their value.Handle ValueChanged event for both controls and in each handler, set the other control's value. Then put your additional logic just in one of the handlers (no matter which one).

Answer (score 0):

Very often you do not need the `sender` and `e` parameters. Therefore just create a parameterless method

```
private void DoSomething() // Hopefully with a better name
{
    // do things ...
}
```

and then call it inside your event handlers.

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething();
}

public void numericUpDown1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

If you give the method a descriptive name, your code becomes easier to read. But of course you could as well just call the other event handler. The event handler is just a method after all

```
public void numericUpDown1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    trackBar1_ValueChanged(sender, e);
}
```

---

Since both of these event handlers have the same signature (the same parameter list and return type), you could declare a single one and attach the same to both controls:

```
void HandleUpdates(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do things...
}
```

And assign it with

```
trackBar1.Scroll += HandleUpdates; 
numericUpDown1.TextChanged += HandleUpdates;
```

You can also assign it in the properties window on the events tab. `new System.EventHandler(...)` is not necessary. C# does it automatically for you.